Python Tkinter Treeview - Apply color to rows based on a specific condition
I'm building a GUI with tkinter and was wondering if there is way to set a background color for rows that meet a certain criteria.
An example:
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog, ttk
import tkinter.font as tkfont
from tkinter.messagebox import OK, INFO, showinfo 
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

class Detail:
    def __init__(self, children):
        self.name = children[0].text
        self.max_amount = int(children[1].text)
        self.curr_amount = 0
        self.scanned = 'red'
        
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.name)
        
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.name == other.name

def conv_part_list_to_table(part_list):
    res = []
    for part in part_list:
        res.append((part.name, part.max_amount, part.curr_amount))
    return res

def conv_part_list_to_colors(part_list):
    res = {}
    for i, part in enumerate(part_list):
        if part.scanned == 'red':
            res[str(i)] = ('white', 'red')
        elif part.scanned == 'green':
            res[str(i)] = ('white', 'green')
        elif part.scanned == 'yellow':
            res[str(i)] = ('black', 'yellow')
    return res

def display_data_in_table(part_list):
    for i, row in enumerate(part_list):
        table.insert('', 'end', values=part_list[i], tags='custom_tag')

def open_xml_file_and_display():
    file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("XML files", "*.xml")])
    if file_path:
        data = conv_part_list_to_table(read_xml_file(file_path))
        colors = conv_part_list_to_colors(read_xml_file(file_path))
        if data:
            display_data_in_table(data)
            apply_colors_to_treeview(table, colors)
            
def handle_input(part_list):
    global cycle_counter, part_counter
    name_inp = text_area.get()
    text_area.delete(0, 'end')
    detail_found = False
    for part in part_list:
        if part.name == name_inp:
            detail_found = True
            if part.scanned != 'green':
                part.curr_amount += 1
                if part.curr_amount == part.max_amount:
                    part.scanned = 'green'
                    part_list.remove(part)
                    part_list.insert(0, part)
                    cycle_counter += 1
                else:
                    part.scanned = 'yellow'
                    part_list.remove(part)
                    part_list.insert(0, part)
                part_counter += 1
                update_treeview(part_list)
                saveXmlTree(part_list)
                apply_colors_to_treeview(conv_part_list_to_colors(part_list))  
            else:
                all_scanned()
            break
    if not detail_found:
        not_found()

def update_treeview(part_list):
    for record in table.get_children():
        table.delete(record)
    for data in conv_part_list_to_table(part_list):
        table.insert("", 'end', values=data, tags='custom_tag')

def apply_colors_to_treeview(table, rows_colors_dict):
    for item, colors in rows_colors_dict.items():
        bg_color, fg_color = colors
        table.tag_configure(item, background=bg_color, foreground=fg_color)

The conv_part_list_to_colors function creates a dictionary with the colors to color the strings in table = ttk.treeview. The apply_colors_to_treeview function applies the previously generated dictionary with colors to my table. However, the problem is that in practice this does not work. Please help me find the error

Please try to pare this down to a [mre] - I suspect much of this code is unrelated to the issue at hand. Reducing this down to the minimum code required to reproduce the problem will not only make this easier for others to work with, it may well help you locate the source of the issue!
